# TYPO3 EXT:realurl + PIWIK parameter pk_vid = issues

Tags: typo3, matomo

We are using TYPO3 EXT:realurl and PIWIK with enableCrossDomainLinking enabled. So each "foreign" URL gets a parameter &pk_vid= added. Sadly, EXT:realurl does process this parameter and as result these links do not work (if there is e.a. a news single page).
I tried to say EXT:realurl to ignore this parameter, but this does not work:

```
'postVarSets' => array(
   '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'piwik' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'pk_vid',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            )
        ),
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: What's the precise error message? What does not work with your pages exactly?

Comment: Links from Page1 to Page2 (both tracked by same piwik with same id and enableCrossDomainLinking enabled) does not work because of pk_vid-parameter. If I remove this parameter from URL, the link/address works in Page2. As example www.domain.org/news/some-title?pk_vid=47542557 does not work / www.domain.org/news/some-title works. I need to learn realUrl to ignore pk_vid-parameter...

Comment: OK, but what exactly does 'does not work' mean? You have any error log messages? If a news detail page does not work, it's because of an additional parameter, that was not part of the cHash generation (see my answer). You can disable RealURL to see all the GET parameters for the detail page, to see what I mean.

Comment: If pk_vid is attached to the URL, every URL shows just one and the same news-item. If pk_vid ist removed, the correct news-item ist displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these parameters to

```
// TYPO3 6.x
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashExcludedParameters'] 
// TYPO3 7.x
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][]
```

Read more about cHash [here](https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Notes-for-Developers)

Comment: Nope, this does not help.